# Binding to List<myType> WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I have `myType1` with one dependency property `string Text`. I crated `myType2` that contains dependency property `ObservableCollection<myType1> Items`. I also have graphical representation of `Items`. When i press button, it sets`myType1.Text` to `null`. When `Item.Text` from `Items` is null I want to delete this item. I try to do this via `

```
private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           ObservableCollection<StringDP> ocdp = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<StringDP>;
            foreach (var sdp in ocdp)
            {
                if (sdp == null)
                {
                    ocdp.Remove(sdp);
                }
            }
            dependencyObject.SetValue(e.Property, ocdp);
        }
```

but it's not raises when Item.Text is setted to null. What am i doing wrong. Thank you!

**Update**

According to documentation `ObservableCollection` doesn't raise `CollectionChanged` event when item's property is changed. I solved my problem by inheritance from `ObservableCollection`.

```
`public class ElObservableCollection<T>: ObservableCollection<T> where T: INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    public ElObservableCollection(): base()
    {
        CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
    }

    public virtual void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                item.PropertyChanged += OnItemChanged;
            }
        }
        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                item.PropertyChanged -= OnItemChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnItemChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "TextProperty" && sender is StringDP)
        {
            StringDP sdp = sender as StringDP;
            if (sdp.Text == null)
            {
                this.Remove((T) sender);
            }
        }
    }

    public ElObservableCollection(List<T> list)
        : base(list)
    {
        CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
    }

    public ElObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        : base(collection)
    {
        CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
    }
}`
```

Comment: should this not raise an enumeration exception --  ocdp.Remove(sdp);
 ?

Comment: yes, that's a mistake, should be sdp.Text == null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation `ObservableCollection` doesn't raise `CollectionChanged` event when item's property is changed. I solved my problem by inheritance from `ObservableCollection`.

```
public class ElObservableCollection<T>: ObservableCollection<T> where T: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ElObservableCollection(): base()
    {
        CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
    }

    public virtual void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                item.PropertyChanged += OnItemChanged;
            }
        }
        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                item.PropertyChanged -= OnItemChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnItemChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "TextProperty" && sender is StringDP)
        {
            StringDP sdp = sender as StringDP;
            if (sdp.Text == null)
            {
                this.Remove((T) sender);
            }
        }
    }

    public ElObservableCollection(List<T> list)
        : base(list)
    {
        CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
    }

    public ElObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        : base(collection)
    {
        CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
    }
}
```

1. In every constructor I subscribe on `CollectionChanged` event.
2. In `CollectionChanged` handler method i subscribe on `PropertyChanged` of each item.
3. In `PropertyChanged` handler method i write needed behavior.
   Guess it will be helpful for somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property inside myType1 that references myType2, this way if the text property inside myType1 is set to null, it can remove itself.

Comment: But it's more clear as it uses the subscriber design pattern, putting this logic inside a list implementation would "hide" this behavior.